# knockout doesn't update values through mapping

Tags: knockout.js

This updates values on a UI:

```
PortfolioGeneral.CompanyName(item.CompanyName);
```

I can write those values hand by hand, but instead I wanted to use a mapping. However this doesn't work:

```
PortfolioGeneral = ko.mapping.fromJS(item);
```

The ko.applyBindings was already called before call of the following function. This call should update all model values.

```
function getPortfolioGeneral(portfolioId, PortfolioGeneral) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/portfolio",
        contentType: "text/json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: portfolioId },
        success: function (item) {            
            //PortfolioGeneral = ko.mapping.fromJS(item);    
            PortfolioGeneral.CompanyName(item.CompanyName);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using the statement `PortfolioGeneral = ko.mapping.fromJS(item);` you are **overriding** the value of your `PortfolioGeneral` so your original observable properties will be replaced with new ones so KO cannot track them anymore.

What you need is to update your `PortfolioGeneral` properties from the data of your `item` object, you can do this with the following syntax:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(
   item, // the source object what you want to map
   {}, // the mapping options if you want something mapped special
   PortfolioGeneral // the target object which you want to be updated
);
```